# Android - циклическое считывание символов из EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, java, строки

Здравствуйте! Есть задача - в EditText пользователь вводит текст и нажимает на кнопку. По нажатию на неё вызывается метод, в котором будет такой алгоритм:

`1. Создать строку data, поместить в неё содержимое EditText
2. Цикл: for(int j = 0; j != data.length(); j++) { достаём из data символ под номером j и выводим его в лог }`

Помогите, пожалуйста, дописать недостающий код!

Comment: И с чем в вышеописанном у вас возникли сложности?

Comment: >Достаём из data символ под номером j

Comment: Гм. `data.charAt(j)`

Comment: Уже пробовал. В логах пусто, а при попытке вывести Toast просто выходит пустое сообщение.


`Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(data.charAt(j)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Подождите, а как Вы создали data ? Точнее, как в неё поместили содержимое из EditText. Все ошибки, о которых Вы говорите, говорят о том, что у Вас data пустой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
String data = editText.getText();
for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++) {
  Log.d("YourLogTag","data[" + j + "] = " + data.charAt(j));
}
```